# disable rows in datagrid silverlight 2.0

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-2.0

I have a datagrid and when user tries to edit a row then I want to have only that row editable and all other rows disabled. Is this possible ? I tried looking for datagrid.rows but there is none.

Please help

Thanks
Sai

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the `BeginEdit` and `EndEdit` events [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid%28VS.95%29.aspx). If the default behavior isn't preventing you from editing the other rows while you are currently editing one you should be able to place some code in those events to disable selecting other rows while in edit mode.